# Is it allowed to copy from Stack Overflow answers or other resources in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, attribution

Stack Overflow Documentation is a perfect idea in order to help developers quickly. I have seen that many topics and examples are copied from other Stack Overflow answers.

So, is it allowed to copy from Stack Overflow answers or other resources in Documentation? Or I can copy, but do I need to quote from where I copied it?

Comment: Hmm, no, Google had the perfect idea to help a developer quickly.  Whether it is ever going to rank Docs higher than SO remains to be seen, right now not a lot of people think so but that's just tea-leave staring.  There is no book of laws and no judge and jury and trying to stop people from wasting their free time is not appreciated.  So what the heck, just go for it.  Just attribute properly.

Comment: "trying to stop people from wasting their free time is not appreciated" LOL.

Comment: I think it would be legitimate to take answers from SO and use them on Docs -- especially if the Q&A is more specific/narrow and then the Docs version is made to be more general. I'm certain that proper citation would be appreciated, but in academia I believe there's a rule of thumb that you don't need a citation if (and only if) the same piece of information is available from 3 or more sources. So if it's a commonly used chunk of code then no citation, but if it's original then definitely cite it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> #### How to reference material written by others
>
> Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is
>   not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your
>   answer being down-voted or deleted.
>
> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all
>   of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

This policy is mentioned on all Stack Exchange sites, so it is no different for Documentation. Just substitute "answer a question" for "write documentation".

Comment: The difference is when I copy some open source work to another open source work and put their attribution on they get credit. When I copy some open source work or SO answer to SO even though they get credit I get reputation. Reputation I don't deserve.

Comment: @gman if you did the work to put useful information somewhere where people will find it, you deserve the rep. Most SO answers are distilling information that's available elsewhere. And most importantly, rep is just fake internet points.

Comment: @hobbs, let's apply that logic you youtube. If you upload a movie that 400 people spent 2 years to make. Do you deserve the rep? Also rep isn't fake internet points as it can be directly exchanged into job offers and salary. In fact recruiters often go through SO and contact those with the high reps

Comment: @gman let's not, because that would be silly. You know that all the Q&A on SO is CC-licensed, right?

Comment: @hobbs, the license has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It has plenty to do with it. If a movie is freely distributable, anyone who uploads it to youtube is welcome to whatever "likes" they get for it, as long as they credit properly; witness the various copies of Big Buck Bunny there :)

Comment: Code is not movies. You just said it was a bad comparison yourself. Rep is the money of SO. Not only does it get you job offers it gives you various permissions as well. Taking someone's Q&A answer and pasting it into Docs seems 100% against the spirit of SO. Ideally there'd be a "copy to docs" button that gave the original poster the rep. Yes I get there'd be issues with that too but the idea at least helps frame the issue being discussed.

Comment: There is a significant caveat here that you're glossing over: "Quote only the relevant portion". That implies that even if you provide attribution (requirements #1 and #3), you can't simply copy-and-paste the entire answer into Documentation. Which seems quite reasonable to me.